# lldb error in Swift - variables not initializing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, function, class, swift

I am new to Swift and have very little experience in Objective-C. This is all I have in my view controller class.

```
var wordString = [String]()


func CallData() {
     self.wordString.append("example string")
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
CallData()
println(wordString[0])
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
```

Why am I getting an "lldb" error and occasionally an "index empty buffer"?

Answer (score 0):

The code compiles and runs fine for me without any error. What version of Xcode are you running? I am running 6.1.1. Perhaps you need to update?